# Why is my App Store Connect 'app preview' the wrong size?

Tags: quicktime, app-store-connect, app-preview

I'm trying to create an App Preview for my ios app in App Store Connect. I'm targeting 6.5" displays.

I successfully created the .mov file using QuickTime, recording my app activity on my iPhone XR. However, when I uploaded the file to App Store Connect, it said **App preview dimensions should be: 1920x886, 886x1920**.

According to [Apple](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8), the *Accepted resolution* is different than the *Native resolution* (see image below).

[image]

How can I create an App Preview if the native size isn't the correct size? Is there a way to use QuickTime or iMovie to either edit or record the right size?

Also, I'm not using Xcode as this is a phonegap project.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to resize the video. Record it first on the targeted device in full resolution. After that you can resize it with tools like iMovie, AfterEffects, ffmpeg or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is, the native resolution is a different aspect-ratio than the accepted resolution. This means that scaling the video alone won't work; the video would actually need to be **cropped** first, then scaled. iMovie doesn't seem to allow precise cropping -- it's done by hand, which won't work because it's not precise.

Comment: Difference is 1-2px. You can definitely size it with ffmpeg or AfterEffects and you won't notice the distortion. (2688/1920 = 1,4; 1242/1,4 = 887,14)

Comment: iMovie will do it very fast

Comment: My god you have to resize them too. You have to create videos in each language, for 6.7", 5.5" as well as those for ipad....no wonder you still don't see app previews very often.

Answer (score 14):

It happened to me as well and I needed to change the format with ffmpeg from .mov to .mp4 in order for the video to be accepted by the App Store Connect.

This command line did the job:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=886:1920,setsar=1:1 output.mp4
```

Comment: I started with an mp4 (from the simulator) needed to adapt this to: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=886:1920,setsar=1:1,fps=60 output.mp4 (and it worked!)

Comment: This really helped because my recorded videos from my phone/simulator were all super annoyingly off by 1px and app store wouldnt accept

Comment: setsar=1:1 is what I needed to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ffmpeg` installed, here's the copy-paste command ([from here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling)):

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=320:240 output.avi`